# Using for loop in csv file in Python

Tags: python

I ran a code in Python 2.7. I have three columns ID1, ID2 and DISTANCE. I want all row values for distance less than 10 metres. When i ran the following code, the output shows all rows. I want DISTANCE to be less than 10 metres.

```
import csv
# open and read the csv file into memory
file = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Data\\2 July\\ndata.csv')
reader = csv.reader(file)
# iterate through the lines and print them to stdout
# the csv module returns us a list of lists and we
# simply iterate through it

if __name__ == "__main__":
file=open("sourav.csv","w") ## open file in write mode
for row in reader:
     if row[3]<='10':

         print "({} {} {})".format(row[1], row[2], row[3])
         file.write("{} {} {}\n".format(row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: row[3] is my distance column in the excel sheet I have. There are different numeric values like 10.9, 34.6 etc. I only want those rows whose values are less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your distance into an integer before you can check it against the value 10:

instead of comparing two strings:

```
if row[3]<='10':
```

you need to compare two integers:

```
if int(row[3])<=10:
```

Comment: Your code shows this error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NEAR_DIST' . Here 'NEAR_DIST' is my distance column.